# Sorting - headers Exception of DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I have a problem with sorting header of datagridview in windows form...

this is my code on CellContentClick

```
 private void dgvApprovazione_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dgvApprovazione.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewLinkCell)
        {//Process link on string
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(dgvApprovazione.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value as string);
        }
    }
```

my datagridview result ..
[image]

but when i click on header columns i have this exception : 
[image]

how to resolve it ?

Comment: You should check if `(e.RowIndex>=0)`

Comment: Copy the actual exception to the clipboard and replace the image above. We believe you, you don't need photo evidence and someone in the future who may have the problem can use a search engine to for that error and find it; which is impossible  from in a photo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check if the clicked cell is not in header row, otherwise when you try to access the cell of the that row, you receive an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` because you tried to get cell at `RowIndex = -1`.

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of
>   the collection.

You need to check if `(e.RowIndex>=0)`

Comment: If the clicked cell is a header row, it should fire the [DataGridView.ColumnHeaderMouseClick](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.columnheadermouseclick%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event

Comment: I think the exception is thrown because of the `Sorting`.

Comment: @J3soon The OP is trying to handle click event of links in the rows. (S)He doesn't want to handle clicks on column header.

Comment: The clicks on the Column Header doesn't fires the `CellContentClick` event

Comment: @J3soon No, It fires `CellContentClick` as well and if you don't check the `RowIndex` as I said, you will receive an exception. I double checked it now :)

Comment: So the header fires the event... I didn't know that... Sorry for the wrong information.

Comment: @J3soon No problem, You may find the answer helpful ;)

Comment: @J3soon By the way, the CellContenClick only fires when you click on text part of header not all parts of header.

Comment: thank so much to both! I have vote :P
..your answers, help to grow

Comment: @RezaAghaei for click on header in part of text or other part i think that depends of windows style-setting... In my windows in any part of click in headers ... Sorting run ..

Comment: I'm using Win 8.1 - `CellContetnClick` only fires when I click on `Text` of Header Cell. To make sure, I should test it on another OS or read source code of it. Anyway you will have no problem by checking `e.RowIndex >=0`.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you've clicked on the header, not a row. 
The `CellClick` fires for both, and passes a `RowIndex` of -1 when you click the header.

Change your code to ignore the event when you click on the header:

```
private void dgvApprovazione_CellContentClick(object sender, 
DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex == -1) return;

    if (dgvApprovazione.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewLinkCell)
    {//Process link on string
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(dgvApprovazione.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value as string);
    }
}
```